# terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range' in C++

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ and learning data structures. In the below code I am getting an "out of range warning", and do not understand what I am doing wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    vector<int> numbers{100,-1,2,4,55,78,3};
    int temp {};
    int pass {};
    pass = numbers.size();
    for(int i {0} ;i<pass-1;i++){    
     for(int j {0} ; j<pass-1-i ; j++){
        if(numbers.at(j) > numbers.at(j+1)){
            temp = numbers.at(j);
            numbers.at(j)=numbers.at(j+1);
            numbers.at(j+1)=temp;
        }   
    }   
    
    }

    cout << numbers.at(0) << endl;
    cout << numbers.at(1) << endl;
    cout << numbers.at(2) << endl;
    cout << numbers.at(3) << endl;
    cout << numbers.at(4) << endl;
    cout << numbers.at(5) << endl;
    cout << numbers.at(6) << endl;
    cout << numbers.at(7) << endl;
    cout << numbers.at(8) << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How can you print `numbers.at(7)` and `numbers.at(8)` from a vector of only seven elements? Use a *loop* to print instead, one where you stay in bounds of the vector. Preferably [a ranged `for` loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for).

Comment: What do you expect ` cout << numbers.at(7) << endl;` and `cout << numbers.at(8) << endl;` to do with only 7 elements in the vector?

Comment: I got, it was a silly mistake I actually changed the length of input and did not realise to change the output, Thanks alot guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you may not understand how `std::vector`s work.

You have only declared `7` elements in your `vector` which means you can only go up to the index `6`. This is because `std::vector`'s indices start at `0`. This is true for `std::array` as well.

`vector<int> numbers{100,-1,2,4,55,78,3};`

However, in your code you have put these two statements:

- `cout << numbers.at(7) << endl;`
- `cout << numbers.at(8) << endl;`

which doesn't work because like I mentioned you can only go up to index `6`.

You should also consider using a `for` loop like the comments mention above. It is more simple to use and is less work.

For example eith a `for` loop:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


int main()
{

    std::vector<int> numbers{ 100,-1,2,4,55,78,3 };
    int temp{};
    int pass{};
   
    pass = numbers.size();
    for (int i{ 0 }; i < pass - 1; i++) {
        for (int j{ 0 }; j < pass - 1 - i; j++) {
            if (numbers.at(j) > numbers.at(j + 1)) {
                temp = numbers.at(j);
                numbers.at(j) = numbers.at(j + 1);
                numbers.at(j + 1) = temp;
            }
        }

    }

std::cout << "v = { ";
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++) {
    std::cout << numbers.at(i) << ", ";
}
std::cout << "}; \n";

return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
v = { -1, 2, 3, 4, 55, 78, 100, };
```

Comment: If a `vector` has 7 elements, then it has 7 indices, not 6. I know you mean the the indices *go up to 6*, but your wording is quite confusing. Could you edit that a bit please?

Comment: Fixed. sorry about that, @cigien.

Comment: No apology needed :) Thanks for incorporating the feedback. I still felt the answer could be a little bit clearer on the point I mentioned, so I edited it a bit. I hope that's ok.

Comment: Yeah of course, thanks for wording it better, @cigien!